# Location of examples folder in Ubuntu

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm trying to add some additional example files to the Arduino IDE in Ubuntu 14.04. However, I can't for the life of me find where the examples are stored in my system. I checked the Arduino website, but can't find any information there. Does anyone know where I need to put my additional files?

Comment: Usually there is no good reason to know where the folder is. The examples are available in Arduino IDE in Files->Examples menu and it doesn't make much sense to add more sketches to built-in examples in local installation.

Answer (score 8):

After some more searching I found it in /usr/share/arduino/examples.

Answer (score 2):

I found mine in Linux Mint 17.3 under `opt/arduino/examples`

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu I found arduino library on
/home/MYUSERNAME/snap/arduino

where MYUSERNAME is user name

Comment: don't install Arduino IDE with snap. it installs some old version